# Unable to execute shellcode in stack with no DEP

Tags: exploit

Here is the simplest example to show my problem. Everything is in WinXp sp3 with DEP disabled.

```
char f() {
    // shellcode starting with some NOPs,
    char shellcode[400]= {
            0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 
            0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 
            0x66, ... some basic shellcode here ...   0x30. 
            0xCC
    };

    // Overwriting Return address in stack to return to NOPs in shellcode above
    b[404]=0xf0;
    b[405]=0xfb;
    b[406]=0x12;
    b[407]=0x00;
}
```

This ended with failure:

```
(920.e7c): Illegal instruction - code c000001d (!!! second chance !!!)
eax=7c801d7b ebx=7c80262c ecx=7c801bfa edx=00060002 esi=00000000 edi=7c802654
eip=0012fc15 esp=0012ff08 ebp=7e410000 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
0012fc15 d9907ca5e490    fst     dword ptr [eax-6F1B5A84h] ds:0023:0d64c2f7=????????
```

But if I execute the shellcode directly, it works:

```
char f() {
    // shellcode starting with some NOPs,
    char shellcode[400]= {
            0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90,  
            0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90,
            0x66, ... some basic shellcode here ...   0x30. 
            0xCC
    };

    void *exec = shellcode;

    ((void(*)())exec)();
}
```

This will work fine.

I did trace the execution in the above two cases. And in both cases, EIP did successfully landed on the NOPs area and continue execution. But I don't know why the first case failed.

One of guess is that in the first case, when f() returns to 0x0012fbf0, the shellcode in the area outside of the stack frame(ie. at that point, the ESP is below the SHELLCODE area) .

Anyone can give an idea why the first case failed?

Comment: The case that fails, are you sending that over the wire? If so, you may want to look at bad characters. Make sure you have bad characters handled. Common examples include null bytes, new lines, and returns. Another thing to look at is the buffer size. Weird things happen when the buffer is too big and you overwrite other areas in memory.

Comment: As hextitan said, bad bytes is the likely culprit. Looking at the address of eip at your crash itis clear that it has continued execution after your eip overwrite.

Comment: A couple of questions: 1) Are you handling the interrupt that you're generating at the end of your shellcode?  That could cause weirdness.  2)  What happens if you only have `nop` instructions in the shellcode?  I would imagine in that case you'd have to make sure you return execution correctly to the original return address.  3) Since you see that EIP is correctly being jumped to (assuming in a debugger), what happens when you step through to the end of the shellcode?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the characters in your shellcode are more than likely considered "bad characters". Bad characters are heavily dependent on *what* the application your exploiting is. You need to look at your shellcode in more detail and figure out what characters are causing the program to throw an exception.

A common way of doing this is by triggering your vulnerability and sending in characters in groups of say 10 and then seeing which ones are correctly represented as hex bytes vs which ones are clearly not. There are also scripts for doing this.

The process of resolving bad characters is commonly achieved using a shellcode encoder. There are a number of them built into msfvenom for example.